# Problems setting tagName property with onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm having some issues changing the tag of an element. This is what I have.

```
<a id="title2" href="#" onclick="this.tagName = 'INPUT'">Click to change element tag.</a>
```

or the longer...

```
<a id="title" href="#" onclick="change_to_textfield()">Click to change element tag.</a>

function change_to_textfield() {
    document.getElementById('title').tagName = 'INPUT';
}
```

I don't get any error messages, and this looks like the correct way to access the tagName property. How come this doesn't work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TagName is a read-only argument. You need to change the element via node-removal or addition. You can also change it via a replace in outerHTML (warning: performance hit).

Answer (score 2):

tagName is a readonly DOM property, see spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-104682815

If you want to transform the `<a>` tag into an `<input>` tag, you'll have to go the hard way and create a new node and put in place of the old one.

Bonus chatter: with a lib like jquery this is relatively easily done:

```
function change_to_textfield() {
  var link = $("#title");
  var textField = $("<input type='text'>").val(link.text());
  link.replaceWith(textField);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`tagName` is just a string, you can't actually change the HTML of an element with it. Would be nice though!